# How to Use a Conditional to Reduce Margin for Object

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, conditional-statements

So there are routines and mastered routines (shown in gold).

If its a mastered routine and appears first in the order then I want to reduce its `margin-top`.

Now that's good in theory. Just do a condition `<% if routine.order == 0 %>`, but then my problem is that if a user checks off that first mastered routine then that mastered routine disappears and then I get that awkward gap again between the title and the next appearing mastered routine.

[image]

What sort of conditional or css-trick/ruby-trick do I need to close this gap?

[image]

**schema**

```
  create_table "routines", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "missed_days",      default: 0
    t.datetime "date_started"
    t.string   "trigger"
    t.string   "action"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "order"
    t.datetime "completed_at"
    t.integer  "days_challenged"
    t.datetime "created_at",                                                                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                                                                          null: false
  end
```

**html**

```
    <div class="page-header-routines">
      <a href="/routines">
        <h2><b>Routine</b></h2>
</a>    </div>
      <table>
  <tbody>
    <div class="routine-padding-home">
          <tr class="routine-space-mastered">
          <td colspan="3">
            <a class="update_routine" id="home_check_mastered" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow" data-method="put" href="/mark_completed/3-read"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="strike-margin-right">
              <a data-modal="true" class="btn" id="gold" href="/routines/3/missed_dates/new">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
</a>            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="gold-standard">
              <a href="/routines/3-read">
                  After I sit with tea,
                I will <span class="label label-warning">read</span>
.
</a>            </div>
          </td>
        </tr> 
    </div>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script>
$('.update_routine').bind('ajax:success', function() {
$(this).closest('table').fadeOut();
});
</script>
```

Comment: You can probably handle this in CSS using `:first` or `:first-of-type` to adjust the appropriate `margin-top`. So what does the HTML look like?

Comment: Updated question @muistooshort with hopefully relevant html

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't invalid HTML? You have a `<div class="routine-padding-home">` as a direct child of a `<tbody>` but [`<tbody>` can only contain `<tr>` children](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/tbody.html#tbody-content-model) so the browser is going to rearrange your HTML. I think your first step is to fix your HTML so that it is valid, that just might fix your visual problem.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do this with JavaScript on the frontend.

Find the next table row from the one you are fading out and set the CSS to be the same as the first one.

Would probably be easier to find the next child if you add a class on all of the table rows so that you can easily find the next of that type.